# Cloc's --force-lang-def works on ubuntu but fails on windows

Tags: cloc

I have next file structure:

```
--root folder
  --Gemfile.lock
  --Gemfile
```

And next language definition:

```
Gem
    filter remove_matches ^\s*#
    filename Gemfile.lock
    filename Gemfile
    3rd_gen_scale 2.11
```

On ubunutu next command:

```
cloc path_to_root_dir --csv --force-lang-def=path_to_def_file
```

Gives me:

> 2 text files.
> 2 unique files.
> 0 files ignored.
>
> files,language,blank,comment,code,"github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.90  T=0.03 s (62.0 files/s, 11467.1 lines/s)"
> 2,Gem,9,5,356
> 2,SUM,9,5,356

And on Windows:

> 2 text files.
> 2 unique files.
> 3 files ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason 1.90 version of cloc requires file names in definition to be lowercase. Adding switch `--ignored="myfile.txt"` resulted in next output:

> path_to_root_dir , zero sized file
> path_to_root_dir/gemfile, language unknown (#3)
> path_to_root_dir/gemfile.lock, language unknown (#3)

And after changing cloc file to have file names in lower case everything started working:

```
Gem
    filter remove_matches ^\s*#
    filename gemfile.lock
    filename gemfile
    3rd_gen_scale 2.11
```

> 2 text files.
> 2 unique files.
> 1 file ignored.
>
> files,language,blank,comment,code,"github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.90  T=0.01 s (278.8 files/s, 51583.6 lines/s)"
> 2,Gem,9,5,356
> 2,SUM,9,5,356

Submitted an issue on [github](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/issues/605).